# Using callbacks to deliver a message once available

Tags: javascript

I'll admit it. The idea of callbacks does not make sense to me right way. I am trying to implement one for my program right now as my variable remains unaltered after modifying it inside of a function.

```
function getMessage(callback) {
        setTimeout(function() {callback(setupAddress(ownerPickupAddressItem));
    }, 0);
}

getMessage(function(ownerPickupAddressItem) {
    console.log(ownerPickupAddressItem);
});

function setupAddress(ownerPickupAddressItem) {
    ownerPickupAddressItem = $('.timeline-item.active-item > .timeline-status > .pickup-address').text();
}
```

I've tested the above and `ownerPickupAddressItem` is still `undefined`. Any idea why?

Comment: Could you show the definition of the `callback` function please?

Comment: *covers face*... I don't have one?

Comment: The idea is not very clear to me, what does the callback function actually do? I have not been able to understand any of the examples presented to date, and see how I can implement it into my project.

Comment: And you shouldn't have one, but you're not returning anything from the last function

Comment: You're assuming that because the arguments have the same name, they will somehow magically be passed by reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `undefined` as you're passing the result of `setupAddress` to your callback.  `setupAddress` doesn't return anything, so it's `undefined`.  Instead, return the value from `setupAddress`:

```
function getMessage(callback) {
        setTimeout(function() {callback(setupAddress(ownerPickupAddressItem));
    }, 0);
}

getMessage(function(ownerPickupAddressItem) {
    console.log(ownerPickupAddressItem);
});

function setupAddress(ownerPickupAddressItem, ownerDropoffAddressItem, waypointsArrayItem) {
    return $('.timeline-item.active-item > .timeline-status > .pickup-address').text();
}
```

Note however that you aren't actually passing any parameters to your `setupAddress` function in a meaningful way - they will all be `undefined`.

Let's simplify it a little:

```
//Fire the callback after 1 second with some text
function getMessage(callback) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        callback("Hello world!");
    }, 1000);
}

getMessage(function(message) {
    console.log(message);
});
```

This calls `getMessage` with a callback designed to take a single parameter.  the `getMessage` function waits 1 second, then fires the callback.

Comment: Thanks. What would I do if I need to return more than one value? I've included the full setupAddress function here: http://pastebin.com/A8CBab3e. I'd need to return `ownerPickupAddressItem`, `ownerDropoffAddressItem` and `waypointsArrayItem`.

Comment: @methuselah Then the callback should take multiple parameters, and be passed to whatever is capable of generating more than one value to be called once all values are known, since you can't return more than one value from any given function.

Comment: It looks like in the code you've presented in the pastebin that you want to assign a value to one of the parameters and have it usable outside of the function?  Javascript doesn't work like that.  You _could_ pass an object in as a parameter, and assign things to properties of that object, then those would be accessible outside of the function.  That's getting out of the realm of callbacks though and probably warrants its own question (or more research!)

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to do something like this

```
var self = this;
function getMessage(callback) {
        /* 
           assuming you have 
           ownerPickupAddressItem, ownerDropoffAddressItem, waypointsArrayItem 
           defined somewhere on self
        */ 
        setTimeout(function() {
            callback.call( self, self.ownerPickupAddressItem,
                                self.ownerDropoffAddressItem,
                                self.waypointsArrayItem      );
        }, 0);
}
```

Basically will pass the function, when the callback is invoked will use the args at that time

The reason you are getting undefined is because here

```
function getMessage(callback) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        //you are calling setupAddress and passing it to the callback
        //setupAddress returns nothing, so it will be undefined
        callback(setupAddress(ownerPickupAddressItem));
    }, 0);
}
```

Also take a look at the  [mozilla docs for call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)  and  [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)  for information how to set the execution context of the callback